# Flagged as duplicate when it is not

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Why would [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/28243/election-system-where-votes-dictate-the-power-of-the-representative) question be flagged as a duplicate when it is not?

There are 3 differences:

1. In the earlier question the weight is determined by the margin and in this system the weight is determined by votes received
2. This deals with the issue of Direct Representation and solves the related issue of Proportional Representation by transferring vote from other constituencies.
3. This question asks about it as a modification to the Westminster system. This implies a whole structured framework with Single Member Plurality and such

Furthermore, the earlier question was never answered. The answers all discussed Proportional Representation (seat to popular vote ratio for parties) which would remain unchanged. Both these systems have an effect on the underlying issue but by changing the power of the individual representative with no reference to the Proportional Representation.